# If the same paper had many contributions in many fields, can I cite each contribution separately?

Tags: citations, writing

I am writing my thesis in computer science and have some issues. 
I have several papers with more than one contribution in many fields (enhancement on several algorithms). 
I want to mention each algorithm with its enhancement separately. Can I cite the same paper in different paragraphs in the literature review?

Comment: Why would you _not_ be able to do so? As long as it's clear you're citing the same paper.

Comment: because I am actually organizing the resources in the literature review according to some criteria so I was worried if citing the same paper might consider not proper way for writing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes

If a paper provides such information that it can be used for several paragraphs - then absolutely you can, and **you actually should**, cite the useful paper whenever and wherever you use the information from within the paper (in your case, the algorithms with their enhancements).

Answer (score 12):

Yes. You should cite a paper every time you talk about it (unless you talk about it multiple times in rapid succession and it's clear that you're still refering to the same thing). There is no "rule" that says you can only refer to a paper once.